# How can I extract just the first td[0] in every tr

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I trying to determine how to best parse the contents of a table with BeautifulSoup with the goal of extracting only the first column ('td") in every row ('tr'). The number of rows in actual table varies based on the search results but the data in each column is consistent I am attempting to use a loop but not doing something correct.

In my code excerpt below, I am just trying to print the first column ('td')  in every row ('tr') by using a loop.

```
doc_req = requests.get(title_url, verify=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(doc_req.content, 'lxml')
doc_body = soup.find('tbody', {'id': 'docs_body'})
doc_entries = doc_body.find_all('tr')

i = 0
for entries in doc_entries:
    data = entries.find_all('td')
    doc_date = data[0]
    print(doc_date.text)
    i+=1
```

My intention is that the script would return the first column (which is the recorded date) of the 2 rows in the example table and then stop.

Once I can accomplish printing the first column (recorded date), I would try and scale up to print the first 3 columns (Recorded Date, Type, Doc Num)

Here is the [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/u9quqZ1L) link to the full table.

Answer (score 0):

I see there are nested tables. You can extract the first `<td>` of outermost table with CSS selector `table#docs_table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1)` (`html_doc` is your HTML code):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

for td in soup.select('table#docs_table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1)'):
    print(td.text)
```

Prints:

```
2000-08-23
2000-04-12
```

---

To scale-up, you can use `zip()` builtin:

```
for rec_date, rec_type, doc_num in zip(soup.select('table#docs_table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1)'),
                                       soup.select('table#docs_table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2)'),
                                       soup.select('table#docs_table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(3)')):
    print(rec_date.text, rec_type.text, doc_num.text)
```

Prints:

```
2000-08-23 CERTIFICATE OF TITLE 00649594
2000-04-12 RELEASE 00254219
```